# how to import image files from multiple directory in a directory

Tags: python-3.x

I have two images per folder inside a single directory. It's like this=
 ######### Main directory ###############
        ##### many folders #########
         #two images per folder#

I need python codes to go inside each of the subfolder and read the images. 
Later I have to perform a set of operations like resize, crop etc etc.

tries using pathlib, but it didn't work well.

Comment: Is this two questions - finding suitable files, then loading them? What went wrong with `pathlib`? Can you post the code and state the problem?

Comment: "but it didn't work well" is not a problem description. Please post a [mcve] and explain how _exactly_ your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with os ?

If your script is located in your main directory, you can try :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import os
thisfolder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

for filename in os.listdir(thisfolder):
    currentFolder = os.path.join(thisfolder, filename)
    # do your things in current folder
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this, It worked for me after some minor modifications.